# Batch that starts python virtual environment and runs the virtual python in a project dir

Tags: python, batch-file, virtual, environment

I want to run each day a python script in a virtual environment by recording it in Windows Task Scheduler.
Hence, I need to write a batch that:

- Opens a cmd.exe
- Starts a virtual environment
- Changes the directory to a python project directory
- Invokes the virtual python

I wrote this .bat:

```
cmd /k "cd /d %USERPROFILE%\python_venv\venv1\Scripts & activate & cd /d %PROJECT_DIR%\src"
python main.py
```

Of course cmd /k does not terminate, and python main.py is not executed.

Sorry in advance if the answer already exists over the Internet but I was not able to find it or to modify a close answer to suit my needs.

[EDIT]
This question is a duplicate of [Schedule [Virtualenv Dependent] Python Script with Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412771/schedule-virtualenv-dependent-python-script-with-windows-task-scheduler).
This post has also not been answered yet.

[EDIT 2]
Found an answer here: [Run a python script in virtual environment from windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622514/run-a-python-script-in-virtual-environment-from-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: I found an answer !
_full_path_to_virtualenv_\Scripts\activate.bat && python _full_path_to_python_script_.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a python script in virtual environment from windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622514/run-a-python-script-in-virtual-environment-from-windows-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

This might be completely irrelevant but I've had a great deal of success using PyCharm + virtual environments with python, you set your VM's file structure up as a project and just add the python environment that you'd like to use with it, it's relatively simple:

Requirements:

- Virtual Env
- Pycharm

Go to ssh to the virtual env and type `which python`

Add remote project interpreter (File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter (cog) add remote) and then type in/select the location for the remote python location

You'll need to set up your file system so that PyCharm can also open the project.

NOTE:

Do not turn off your virtual environment without saving your run configurations that will cause pycharm to see your run configurations as corrupt
There's a button on the top right that reads share enable this and your run configs will be saved to a .idea file and you'll have a lot less issues

Comment: I agree with you. I knew this was possible with pycharm. But in my case, i just wanted to quickly start en virtual environment in a specific directory and start working in it.

Comment: I also want to start my process each day thanks to Windows Task Scheduler. So the PyCharm solution does not work.